# Python: How can I call the vairables of a member method from another method in the same class?

Tags: python-3.x, oop

I am trying to refer to variables (x1,x2,x3,x4) of a member function (distance) inside another method (slope) within the same class. However, it's throwing an error. What am I doing wrong?

```
class Line():

def __init__ (self,cor1,cor2):
    self.cor1 = cor1
    self.cor2 = cor2

def distance(self):
    x1 = self.cor1[0]
    y1 = self.cor1[1]
    x2 = self.cor2[0]
    y2 = self.cor2[1]
    return math.sqrt((x2-x1) ** 2 + (y2-y1) ** 2)

def slope(self):
    return (self.y1-self.y2)/(self.x1-self.x2)
```

I tried moving it to the **init** method and it works. The following code works for me. However, is there a way to call x1,x2,y1,y2 which are variables of one method from another?

```
class Line():

def __init__ (self,cor1,cor2):
    self.cor1 = cor1
    self.cor2 = cor2
    self.x1 = self.cor1[0]
    self.y1 = self.cor1[1]
    self.x2 = self.cor2[0]
    self.y2 = self.cor2[1]

def distance(self):
    return math.sqrt((self.x2-self.x1) ** 2 + (self.y2-self.y1) ** 2)

def slope(self):
    return (self.y1-self.y2)/(self.x1-self.x2)
```

Comment: No. Why would you want that? Objects and members were born precisely for this reason (and avoid globals). Note you could just use `self.cor1/2` in both functions. If you always convert them to `x` and `y` (or even most of the time), why even keep them like that and not as `x` `y` members?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do that; further, the use of global variables is not recommended inside classes.

Your OOP design could use a `class Point` to represent a pair of coordinates; that class should also hold the `distance` method.

In the following example, I added a `length` method to the `class LineSegment`, as a `property`, so you can access it like an `attribute`:

```
class Point:
    """represents a pair of coordinates
    """

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def distance(self, other):
        return ((other.x - self.x)**2 + (other.y - self.y)**2)**.5


class LineSegment:
    """represents a line segment with its start and end Point
    """

    def __init__ (self, start, end):
        self.start = start
        self.end = end        

    def slope(self):
        denom = (self.start.x - self.end.x)
        return (self.start.y - self.end.y) / (self.start.x - self.end.x) if denom else float('inf')

    @property
    def length(self):
        return self.start.distance(self.end)


cor1 = Point(1, 2)
cor2 = Point(3, 4)

line = LineSegment(cor1, cor2)
print(line.slope(), line.length)
```